# how to remove next words start from next paragraph in using css

Tags: css

here is Text "Motivational Quotes"

The Problem is it showing like this

"

Motivational

Quotes

"

If the word is Three Line

"
Motivational

Quotes

T-shirts

"

The next words start from next paragraph..
How to fix with the help of css so the next words start like this "Motivational Quotes"

```
.custom-image-cat-style-2 .tbay-element-custom-image-list-categories.widget-categories.widget-grid .item-cat .cat-name {
top: 105px;
left: 42px;
right: auto;
color: #000000;
font-size: 13px;
```

}

Comment: Post HTML as well, then we won't be guessing what your problem might be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably changing, in some parent of `.custom-image-cat-style-2 .tbay-element-custom-image-list-categories.widget-categories.widget-grid .item-cat .cat-name` the property `white-space`, check it.

If you add `white-space: normal;` to css of the text, it should show normal
I recomend you to check this web site: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp